# Limit of a sequence using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have a sequence $a_n$ such that its limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ is $0$. Using the definition of the limit, I can write:
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}; \forall n > N, |a_n| < \epsilon$$

Let $b_n$ be a certain sequence. Then, from the above equation, taking $\epsilon = |b_n|$, I can write:
$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N}; \forall n > N, |a_n| < |b_n|$$

Would that be correct?

Comment: Would what be correct? Be more precise.

Comment: I've updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: do you mean $n\rightarrow 0$ or $\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @Alessandro: sorry, I fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your statement is:

$a_n \to 0$ and $(b_n) \subset (0,\infty)$ implies there exist $N$ such that $|a_n| <|b_n|$ for all $n >N$

then it is certainly false. Just take $b_n=\frac {|a_n|} 2$ when $a_n \neq 0$ and $b_n=1$ otherwise. The conclusion will hold only when $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $$\lim _{n\to \infty}b_n =0$$ then you know that  $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}; \forall n > N, |b_n| < \epsilon$$

Thus if you prove that $$  \exists N \in \mathbb{N}; \forall n > N, |a_n| < |b_n|$$ Then you have proved that $$\lim _{n\to \infty}a_n =0$$ as well.